# @2x images not loading in some iPhone 4 devices

Tags: iphone-4, retina-display

I've added both image.png and image@2x.png in my resource folder. My problem is, in some iPhone4 devices it is loading the image@2x.png  correctly while in some it is taking the image.png file. Please help me in this as I couldn't find any obvious reason for this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this test. Turn both devices off and restart them. They both should load the retina image if their iOS is the same version. I guessing the iPhone that doesn't load the retina image has a lot of background applications running. I believe if memory is below a certain threshold non-retina images are loaded instead.